# Entity Framework: Access/ debug SQL

Tags: abp

I like to view my SQL queries generated by AdpDbContext in my logging infrastrucutre.

I come accross following article https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/logging-in-entityframework-core.aspx but I am not sure how to integrate it with the existing abp infrastructure?

Can you please give me a hint how I can log the SQL queries to the existing Logging infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

When run a project HTTP Api  on VS2019 you can get access to this information on output console log. All the information is shown on this feature. Check it out...
[image: Output]